# Push to View Controller in parserDidEndDocument() - IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xml-parsing

I'm trying to push to View Controller names "HomeViewController" after processing xml tags, 
I want to navigate to "HomeViewController"screen  in parserDidEndDocument method,

```
-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
[self.delegate parsingComplete:catalogArray];
// Here i need to push to HomeViewController

}
```

Please can anybody give me an idea to do this

Answer (score 0):

HomeViewController *homeView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyBoardIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:homeView animated:YES];